# Tail-recursive programs in F#

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

Hi I am trying to do this exercise but can't quite figure it out. I am given the following code in F#

```
type A<’a> = | D of ’a * bool
             | E of A<’a> * A<’a>

let rec g acc x = match x with
             | E(y,z) -> g (g acc z) y
             | D(a,true) -> a::acc
             | _ -> acc;;

let h x = g [] x;;
```

The exercise is now to argue if g is a tail-recursive function or not and to provide declarations of continuation-based, tail-recursive variants of both g and h.
Hope someone can help!

Answer (score 0):

*g* is not tail recursive since it first needs to resolve the internal *g* call within the outer *g*, basically using the stack until the internal call is resolved.

Applying CPS this could be rewritten as

```
let rec g acc x cont = 
  match x with
    | E(y,z) -> g acc z (fun acc->g acc y id)
    | D(a,true) -> a::acc |> cont
    | _ -> acc |> cont
```

and called like

```
let h x = g [] x id
```

Continuations are passing as a parameter of the function what next you want to resolve.  For example in the case of nodes type *E*, we solve *z* and then ask to solve as a continuation *y*.    The continuation is solved in the terminal cases *D*.

The *id* is the identity function basically for the last call since we do not need to do anything.